# Não consigo fazer OnBlur/OnValueChanged

Tags: angular, devexpress

Estou usando o `DevExpress`, quando faço direto pelo `HTML` funciona, mas com o `dxi-item` não, provavelmente porque estou utilizando `onValueChanged` de maneira incorreta...

**FORMA 1**

**Component.html**

```html
<dxi-item
  dataField="cep"
  autocomplete="off"
  [colSpan]="2"
  [label]="{text: 'CEP'}"
  [editorOptions]="{onValueChanged: cepChanged}">
</dxi-item>
```

**Component.ts**

```
ConsultaCEP(cep) {
   console.log("Consultar CEP: " + cep);
}
cepChanged(e){
   this.ConsultaCEP(e.value);
}
```

**Não entra no LOG**

**Erro**

> ERROR TypeError: this.ConsultaCEP is not a function

**FORMA 2**

**Component.html**

```html
<dxi-item
  dataField="cep"
  autocomplete="off"
  [colSpan]="2"
  [label]="{text: 'CEP'}"
  [editorOptions]="{onValueChanged: ConsultaCEP}">
</dxi-item>
```

**Component.ts**

```
ConsultaCEP(e) {
   console.log("Consultar CEP: " + e.value);

   this.service.consultaCEP(e.value)
     ....
}
```

**Resultado do LOG**

Consulta CEP: 0123456

**Erro**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'consultaCEP' of undefined

**Repito**, em ambas as formas, fazendo com HTML funciona.

Faz 2 dias que mandei mensagem para o suporte deles e não obtive resposta...

Comment: pq seu metodo começa com letra maiuscula?

Comment: Não fui eu quem fiz, só sou responsável pela manutenção e é serio q isso é relevante? São boas praticas, ok, mas né...

Answer (score 0):

Usando a FORMA 2 descrita acima, eu dei um bind e funcionou:

```
construtor(private service: Service){
    this.ConsultaCEP = this.ConsultaCEP.bind(this);
}
```